# Proof that Somos-k sequence contains a non-integer for k > 7

Tags: combinatorics

Many different sources say that all the Somos-k sequences for k>7 have non-integer terms. However, none of them give a proof! Where can I find one? Thanks!

Comment: Have you followed all the links at http://faculty.uml.edu/jpropp/somos.html ?

Comment: http://oeis.org/A030127 gives "Term at which n-Somos sequence first becomes nonintegral." Have you checked the references at that page?

Comment: Yeah I looked at both of these pages and didn't find any proofs.  It's possible that I'm just bad at looking though.